# Getting rid of numbers

Tags: numbering, titles, datetime

How would I get rid of the date, and the numbers 1 and 2? My latex code is below. I cant post images as Im a new user, sorry!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\begin{document}

\title{Banana Cake}
\maketitle


\section{Ingredients}

\begin{itemize}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc
\end{itemize}

\section{Method}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `\date{}` and starred versions of `section`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\begin{document}

\title{Banana Cake}
\date{}
\maketitle


\section*{Ingredients}

\begin{itemize}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc
\end{itemize}

\section*{Method}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc
\end{enumerate}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

As per the comments of **Enrico** (egreg), if none of the sections need to be numbered, one may use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` in the preamble. This will allow one to use the regular `section` (without having numbers). This will also enable the use of section titles as the headers.

Comment: If *no* section should have a number, it's easier to write `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` in the preamble and use `\section`; this would take care of headers, should `\pagestyle{headers}` be called.

Comment: @egreg Nice point. I have included it in the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

You should use `\section*{Ingedients}` (with the star), and you should add `\date{}` into your preamble, like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\title{Banana Cake}
\maketitle


\section*{Ingredients}

\begin{itemize}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc
\end{itemize}

\section*{Method}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

I would recommend you to read some good LaTeX tutorial since these are quite basic things, you can find some hints here: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/11002)

Comment: Thanks, it works :) Will check the referred links above :)