# Section list without numbering?

Tags: sectioning

I do not want the section numbered, i.e., Roman number `I.` (as the following figure show). How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: `\section*{}`??

Comment: Can you post a MWE?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that you want the section to be unnumbered as this has nothing to do with indexing as far as can be seen.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thx.

Comment: This has *got* to be a duplicate.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, but it is harder to find because the list of potential duplicates on the right doesn't seem in anyway sensitive to the editing I did and is still listing a load of questions about indexing.

Comment: This seems very much a subset of [Getting rid of numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77874/5764).

Comment: Or of part of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/creating-unnumbered-chapters-sections-plus-adding-them-to-the-toc-and-or-header)?

Comment: @cfr I agree, I have searched the answer and empty handed, it's my belief that the algorithm of website should be improved.

Comment: Google is much better at searching StackExchange than StackExchange is.

Comment: @SeanAllred totally agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an unnumbered section using

```
\section*{Section Title}
```

Similar starred commands exist for other divisions of the document e.g. `\chapter*{}` (in books and reports), `\subsection*{}` etc.